# Comparing array of hashes with regex in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, rspec

I have two array of hashes. Actual array is one I'm getting through my test and I have expected array stored somewhere in files with which I compare the actual one.

- Actual array

  `[
    {:var1=>nil, :action=>"open", :Run=>"App", :Id=>"A123-B456-C789"}, 
    {:var1=>nil, :Id=>"P987-Q654-R321"}
  ]`
- Expected array

  `[
    {:var1=>nil, :action=>"open", :Run=>"App", :Id=>"A123-B456-C789"},
    {:var1=>nil, :Id=>"P987-Q654-R321"}
   ]`

Currently, I am using Rspec::Matcher [match_array](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/contain-exactly-matcher) to compare and it is working perfectly:

```
expect(actual).to match_array(expected)
```

**Problem**:

**Id** in actual array in every hash is dynamic. So, I can not compare it with expected value. Here, I would like compare if it is not nil or check pattern with some regex. Something like this:

```
{:var1=>nil, :Id=> !nil or /some-regex/}
```

Not sure if it's doable with Rspec Matcher or I need to change matcher library?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use a double:

```rb
let(:id_double) { double('id') }
let(:expected) do
  [
    { var1: nil, action: 'open', Run: 'App', Id: id_double },
    { var1: nil, Id: id_double }
  ]
end

before do
  allow(id_double).to receive(:==) do |other_id|
    other_id =~ /^[A-Z]\d{3}-[A-Z]\d{3}-[A-Z]\d{3}$/
  end
end

it 'works' do
  actual = # ...
  expect(actual).to match_array(expected)
end
```